# Access Nuxt.js context in Vue plugin

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm using Nuxt.js and I have two plugins installed.
I need access to the VueI18n instance from lang.js in validate.js

Does someone know how to do this?

---

*lang.js*

```
Vue.use(VueI18n)

export default ({ app }) => {
  app.i18n = new VueI18n({
    locale: 'en',
    messages
  })
}
```

---

*validate.js*

```
Vue.use(VeeValidate, {
  i18nRootKey: 'validations',
  i18n,  // access the VueI18n instance from plugin above
  dictionary: {
    en: validationMessages
  }
})

export default ({ app }) => {
  // This way I could get the instance but how to add it to the plugin?
  console.log(app.i18n)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just move your vue.use inside export default

```
export default ({ app }) => {

Vue.use(VeeValidate, {
  i18nRootKey: 'validations',
  i18n: app.i18n,  // access the VueI18n instance from plugin above
  dictionary: {
    en: validationMessages
  }
})
}
```